# The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c# VS 2013

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I added reference to MySql.Data.dll from mysql connector 6.9.10 installation. But still i get error: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) using c# in VS 2013

Comment: i have both using MySql.Data; and using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; stmts in my .cs file

Comment: can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the version incompatibility of .Net and Mysql i was using. My project is compiled with .net 3.5 and am trying to use Mysql.data dll from connector 6.9. Issue resolved after using dll from MySql connector 6.3.9/v2.0. Too bad that the error is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

On the *.cs file you are trying to use the  MySql connector, you need a Using Statement.

Go to the line that you have the error on, the red squiggly. put the cursor on the word and press Ctrl . (period)  You'll be presented with an option to add the using statement to the top of the file.

Comment: i have both using MySql.Data; and using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; stmts in my .cs file

Comment: the mySQL connector Version should be compatible with your VS version e.g. I was using VS 2012 and could not connect using MySQL connector 7 or above! So I down graded to v.6.3.9. This connector version works on all projects regardless of .NET version (within VS 2012).